# How to print the longest line number for each file in a directory?

Tags: unix, escaping, find

I'm trying to list the max line length for files in the current directory, but I'm having trouble with my command working.  I believe it's an issue with escaping the curly brackets `{}` in my exec command. After googling through a ton of find exec escape answers I wasn't able to locate anything about how to escape  brackets `{}` in the exec command.  What am I missing?

```
find . -iname *.page -exec awk '{if(length($0) > L) { LINE=$0;L = length($0)}} 
END {print LINE"|"L}' {}\; | sort
```

Comment: You need a space between the `{}` and the `\;`.

Comment: Yep, there were numerous issues with my original, none of which was actually relating to escaping `{}`, a space between the `{}` and `\;`.  Thanks for pointing that out I'll update the final answer so the next user can benefit from your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their are multiple issues with the original command none of which are escaping `{}`.  The first issue is there needs to be a space between `{}` and `\;`.  The second issue is related to how the shell expands the wildcard in the find iname paramater `*.page`.

From the [Free BSD Forums](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=29885)

> "*" is expanded by the shell before the command-line is passed to find(1). If there's only 1 item in the directory, then it works. If
>   there's more than one item in the directory, then it fails as the
>   command-line options are no longer correct.

Wrapping the *.page in quotes solves the issue.  The final version is

```
find . -iname '*.page' -exec awk '{if(length($0) > L) 
{ LINE=NR;L = length($0)}} END {print L"|"FILENAME":"LINE}' {} \; | sort -n
```

Which outputs the a sorted list of the longest line for each file with line number

```
220|./Example1.page:157
206|./Example2.page:203
```

Comment: need `sort -n` here

Answer (score 1):

You want to run awk on each file, right?

create a script: t.sh in your home directory:

```
awk '{if(length($0) > L) { LINE=$0;L = length($0)}} 
END {print LINE"|"L}' "$1"
```

command line:

```
find . -iname *.page -exec ~/t.sh {} | sort
```

I'm not too sure about your awk script but since you think it is what you need let's pass on that for now.

Comment: Thanks, that would definitely work.  That said, any idea how I could pass in an expression to -exec that includes brackets?

Comment: Please post the expression.  By brackets you probably mean some type of pattern matching...

Comment: looks like i jumped the gun, it's not the brackets it's awk, this works just find `find . -iname "*.cls" -exec echo '{if(length($0) > L) { LINE=$0; L = length($0)}} END {print LINE"L"L}' {} \;`

Comment: ended up the issues was the *.page in the find, this gets expanded incorrectly in awk (see this [forum](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=29885)), surrounded "*.page" in quotes fixes the issue, if you'd like to update your answer I'll re-accept

Comment: You are fixed, that's good, and I don't care about rep very much.  Thanks.